# Extract Month/Year from Date in SSRS 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am using SQL Server SSRS 2008 version and I need to extract out of a date field, the Month and Year values.  For example from   2013-01-11 21:11:29.340,  I need the report to display “January 2013”

In design view, in the cell where I want the information to display, where the ‘Expression’ option from the pull down menu, I put

```
= DATENAME(MONTH, DesiredDate) & DATENAME(YEAR, DesiredDate) .
```

And got an error message.

BTW, the ‘DesiredDate’ comes from the SQL code in the Query Designer.

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: The error message indicates incorrect syntax

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In SQL Server to concatenate values you will need a `+` between the values:

```
DATENAME(MONTH, DesiredDate) +' '+ DATENAME(YEAR, DesiredDate)
```

You might need to use the `&' '&` which will add the whitespace between the values:

```
DATENAME(MONTH, DesiredDate) &' '& DATENAME(YEAR, DesiredDate)
```

Edit #1, based on your comment, you can use the following in the Expression window:

```
=MonthName(Month(Fields!desireddate.Value)) &" "& Year(Fields!desireddate.Value)
```

Note: I just tested this in SSRS 2008 and it returned the result that you want.

Comment: Hi Bluefeet, Do you know if I could put the suggested code above in the EXPRESSION menu option in SSRS 2008 ?

Comment: @Joe See my edit, I just tested a version that worked in SSRS 2008.

Comment: Thank you. BTW, the date that I need (that desireddate field) is declared as a part of a table in the SQL code.  Do you know if I need to define it as a parameter or a variable in order to be able to use that line of code that you suggested above ?  thanks

Comment: @Joe The `Fields!desireddate.Value` value came from a table that I was using when I tested it, so that line should work.